# how to calculate $\int_C \frac{2xy^2dx-2yx^2dy}{x^2+y^2},$ where $C$ is the ellipse $3x^2 +5y^2 = 1$ taken in the positive direction.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate $$\int_C \frac{2xy^2dx-2yx^2dy}{x^2+y^2},$$ where $C$ is the ellipse $3x^2 +5y^2 = 1$ taken in the positive direction.

$\\$

> my trial  :

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$The Elipse

$x(t) = \frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{3}}$
$~y(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{5}}$

$t \in [0,2\pi]$

$ dx = \frac{-\sin(t)}{\sqrt{3}}~dt$

$ dy = \frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{5}}~dt$

$ 2xy^2~dx = \frac{2\cos(t)}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sin(t)^2}{5}\frac{-\sin(t)}{\sqrt{3}}~dt = \frac{-2\cos(t)\sin(t)^2\sin(t)}{15}~dt$

$ -2yx^2~dy = \frac{-2\sin(t)}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\cos(t)^2}{3}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{5}}~dt = \frac{-2\cos(t)\cos(t)^2\sin(t)}{15}~dt$

$ x^2 + y^2 = \frac{\cos^2(t)}{3} + \frac{\sin^2(t)}{5} = \frac{3+2\cos^2(t)}{15}$

so  $~\int_C \frac{2xy^2dx-2yx^2dy}{x^2+y^2} = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-2\sin(t)\cos(t)}{3+2\cos^2(t)}~dt = \frac{ln(3+2\cos^2(t))}{2}|_0^{2\pi} = 0$

Comment: "It can't be coincidence"? Why not? Even if you do it in three different ways it could be a coincidence...

Comment: maybe , can you check what is wrong with my answer please.

Comment: For example: $$x^2+y^2=\frac{\cos^2t}3+\frac{\sin^2t}5=\frac{5\cos^2t+3\sin^2t}{15}=\frac{\color{red}3+2\cos^2t}{15}\;\ldots$$

Comment: But I see you wrote the correct expression in the integral in the last line, and thus I can't see any problem here. Why do you think that answer is incorrect?

Comment: because someone gave me another answer last night , it is duplicated post .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065565/how-to-calculate-int-c-frac2xy2dx-2yx2dyx2y2-using-green-theorm-or?noredirect=1#comment6320933_3065565

Comment: If you mean John Doe’s answer to that question, note that he only integrated over a quarter of the ellipse. He’s updated that answer to explain that the integral over the entire ellipse does vanish.

Comment: ...and you can't apply Green's theorem as the domain enclosed by your line (the ellipse) isn't simply connected.